# How do we ask someone about the days of their routines?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Which one is correct? If all are, which one is more common?

**1. What days do you go swimming?**

**2. What day do you go swimming?**

**3. On what days do you go swimming?**

Answer (score 2):

All three of these are correct.

> 1. What days do you go swimming

This would be asked if the questioner has reason to believe that the person being questioned swims on more than one day.

> 2. What day do you go swimming

This would be asked is the questioner believes that the person being asked only swims on one day.

> 3. On what days do you go swimming

This is equivalent to 1 in meaning and nuance.  If I had to manufacture a difference, I'd say that 3 is slightly less formal than 1.